# Stuck at one simple PHP UPDATE table, UPDATE just do nothing

Tags: php

This code is just refreshing my page. I cant see any errors. Maybe someone else can see the error here in code? I have the same code in two other pages and they do `UPDATE`.

The code below is in one page:

```
<body>
<?php
$query=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","","mydb") or die ("Ne moga da se svyrja s bazata danni.");

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$datetime=$_POST['datetime'];
$vlekach_teltur=$_POST['vlekach_teltur'];
$driver1=$_POST['driver1'];
$telnomer=$_POST['telnomer'];
$belejka=$_POST['belejka'];
$user=$_POST['user'];


mysqli_set_charset($query,"utf8");
$sql="update teltur set datetime = '$datetime', vlekach_teltur = '$vlekach_teltur', driver1 = '$driver1', telnomer = '$telnomer', belejka = '$belejka', user = '$user' where id='$id'";
$query3 = mysqli_query($query, $sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL:     $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);

if(mysqli_query($query3, $sql)){
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function redir()
{
alert('Успешен запис!');
window.location.assign('index.php');
}
</script>
<body onload='redir();'></body>";
} 
else{
echo "Не успешен запис, свържете се с администратора $query3. " . mysqli_error($query);
}
}
mysqli_set_charset($query,"utf8");
$sql2="select * from teltur where id='$id'";
$query1=mysqli_query($query, $sql2);
$query2=mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
?>
<h3 style="text-align:center;">Редакция на телефони Турция</h3>
<form id="docContainer" class="fb-toplabel fb-100-item-column selected- object" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
 <div id="section1" class="section">   
   <div id="column1" class="column ui-sortable">
    <div class="fb-grouplabel">

      <p>Дата<input type="text" id="datetime" name="datetime" value="<?php echo $query2['datetime']; ?>"/>
      <label id="datecheckalert" style="color: red; font-style: italic;">    </label></p>
    </div>
    <p>Влекач:
    <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $query2['vlekach_teltur']; ?>">
    </p>
     <div id="scrollable-dropdown-menu">
     <p>Шофьор:
    <input type="text" name="driver1" class="driver1 tt-query" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $query2['driver1']; ?>">
      </p>
  </div>
 <div id="scrollable-dropdown-menu">
 <p>Телефонен номер:
    <input type="text" name="telnomer" class="telnomer tt-query" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $query2['telnomer']; ?>"/>
   </p>
 </div>

<p>Забележка:
    <input type="text" name="belejka" value="<?php echo $query2['belejka']; ?>"/>
</p>

<p>Потребител:
<select id="user" name="user">
        <option value="<?php echo $query2['user']; ?>"><?php echo $query2['user']; ?></option>

    </select></p>
   <p align="center">
    <input type="submit" value="ЗАПИС" />
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>
   <?php
}
?>
</form>
</body>
```

I have error reporting as you see but no errors found.

Comment: Why you write mysqli_query two times? just use once by if condition.

Comment: Because i have to show the values from selected row in the table.

Comment: You can doit by putting it in if query only

Comment: Im sorry to ask but do you know how it will be? I mean this is dificult for me for now. I have `submit` in one `if` statement now.

Comment: Just change if($query3){ . that's it. you already executed query upside.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah im so stupid, i missed to name the Submit button.

```
 <input type="submit" value="ЗАПИС" />
```

Changed to this code: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ЗАПИС" />`
I spend tree hours and after make a post here i found it by my self. 
Can some one just delete this thread?